# Frequency distribution of items of each list in latex

Tags: list, count, latex, items

I have a .tex file with many "enumerate" lists.
Can I produce a table where I have the name of each list and the number of items within each list?
For example I would like the outcome to be something like this

List 3 25

List 1 10

List 2 8

List 4 5

and so on. 
This means that list 3 has most items (25), list 1 has 10 items, and so on. 
Is this possible in latex?